# Pushing old items from storage into array with new items and than saving all items to storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an app that is like a shopping cart. Users search for a product and can add it to their cart. After adding it they can checkout or go back and add more items.

The problem is that when a new item is added, the old items are taken and put into an array of objects. However the old items also remain as objects An example

```
Object1
Object2
Array[Object1, Object2]
Object3

[Object, Object, Array(2), Object]
```

If I add another item it will become

```
[Object1, Object,2 Array(2), Object3, Array(4), Object4]
```

What am I doing wrong?

dataStorage.ts

```
temp = [];
temp2 = [];

// How data is saved 
save(data): Promise<any> {
  return this.getData().then((products: any[]) => {
    if (products) {
      //this.temp = products;
      this.temp.push(products, data);
      console.log(this.temp);
      return this.storage.set('products', this.temp);
    }
    return this.storage.set('products', data);
  });
}
```

// How data is returned

```
getData() {
  return this.storage.get('products');
}
```

component.ts

```
// they click on an add button that calls this 
saveItem() {

let newItem = {
  prodName: this.prodName,
  prodDesc: this.prodDesc
};

this.dataService.save(newItem).then(()=>{
  this.navCtrl.pop(SearchProducts);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `products` is array in case storage had it, so push array to `temp` array will be array in array , not concat.

```
temp = [];
temp2 = [];

// How data is saved 
save(data): Promise<any> {
  return this.getData().then((products: any[]) => {
    if (products) {
      products.push(data);
      return this.storage.set('products', products);
    }
    return this.storage.set('products', [data]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this before and it was giving me an error saying I couldn't push to products but thats because I was missing `[data]`